# How to SELECT most recent record in kSQL

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, ksqldb

Each record in a Stream has `CREATEDAT` integer value such as `1657208128653` and the Stream was created with:

```
CREATE STREAM my_stream (NAME STRING, CREATEDAT INT) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'my_topic', PARTITIONS=2, VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON');
```

I want to SELECT a single the most recent record.

Running this command results to no output:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as count FROM my_stream TIMESTAMP BY CREATEDAT GROUP BY name, TUMBLINGWINDOW(seconds,10);
```

How to correct this SELECT statement so it returns a most recent record? Is there a way to sort the records by timestamp in ksql?

Comment: `select * from my_stream order by TIMESTAMP desc LIMIT 1`

Comment: I'm not a Kafka user, but `GROUP BY TIMESTAMP` just seems like a query-smell to me, as `TIMESTAMP` values will be highly distinct, no?

Comment: `select * from my_stream order by TIMESTAMP desc LIMIT 1` causes  `mismatched input 'BY' expecting {';` error

Comment: *"Keywords are reserved tokens that have a specific meaning in ksqlDB's syntax."* 
`timestamp` is a KSQLDB "keyword" see: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/sql/appendix/#keywords are you certain the column is actually named "TIMESTAMP"?

Comment: Using any other column names results to the same error `mismatched input 'BY' expecting {'`

Comment: Could you try the following (to try to get _some_ output): add `SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';` to let the new query read from the start of the topic and add `EMIT CHANGES` at the very end the `SELECT` statement?